# Vertical divider inside ListTile header

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am attempting to add vertical divider between the leading portion and the title of a ListTile.

I understand that Flutter now has a VerticalDivider widget, but I can't seem to get it to work properly with the ListTile. Example of what I am trying to do is attached.

[image: I am attempting to replicate this list tile in the attached image.]

This was tagged as a possible duplicate post, but it is not. Just because the other post has VerticalDivider in the title doesn't mean that it is asking the same question. Maybe the person who tagged it as a duplicate should actually read the post instead of just browse the title...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use a `Row` widget inside the `leading` property of the `ListTile`

```
ListTile(
          leading: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
              VerticalDivider(),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text("QUICK REFERENCE"),
        ),
```

Comment: That worked! I tried a row earlier, but forgot to set the mainAxisSize to min, which completely wiped out the title. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to change the height of the vertical divider? Because like in the picture it doesn't span the whole listTile but when I implement it it covers the entire height of the listTile